# How to show/hide other applicaitions opened by urlscheme with cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, url-scheme, inappbrowser

I have two applications built with cordova and my target platform is only android.

- Application 1 shall open Application 2.
- After doing some stuff, Application 2 shall be hidden (not stopped!) and Application 1 shall be shown again.
- When the user decides, it shall be possible to open Application 2 again.

Current approach:
I use cordova-plugin-customurlscheme and cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open the other application. But opening another application in inappbrowser needs the _system browser.

Problem:
When i open the app with _system, I dont have any control from app1 in app2 and the js in app1 is stopped I think.

`var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('mycoolapp://url', '_system', 'location=yes');`

When app2 ist started, I cannot execute any js injected from app1, like hiding it. Any callback attached to ref (loadstart, loadstop...) doesnt execute. Only, if _blank is used, but it is not possible to open applications in _blank. :(

It is only possible that app2 closes itself with navigator.app.exitApp(), and app1 is visible again. But, when I open app2 next time, it has to bootstrap and start the whole app and that needs a lot of time.

Is there any other way to show/control/open another app with url scheme on android.

Maybe, like on iOS, that I dont have to start an extra instance of app2 inside app1, and just open the "real" instance of app2? Because on android it looks, like an extra instance of app2 was started and it is possible to start many app2 instances...

Comment: instead of exiting from app 2, open app 1 from it.

Comment: I will give it a try, but on android I think, only a second instance of app1 will be started. I will tell you :) Thanks!

Comment: As I thought :( a new second instance of app1 ist started... :(

Comment: don't know about cordova, but in Android you can specify whether you want a new instance, or an old one